# This application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way QT C++

Tags: c++, dll

I am developing a Fifteen Puzzle Game in `QT C++`. Game works sometimes fine and sometimes crashed during run. I don't know the problem. I looked into different forums and found different suggestions. Some say this error is due to missing `dll` etc.

A window appears with Error is below

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
This application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: Is this the *full* error message from the message box? Qt4 or Qt5?

Comment: This is not due to missing dll. With just this information, the possible reasons could be too many to even mention here. Please provide more information.

Comment: @typ1232 Yes this is complete message written in the message window. QT Creator 2.0.1 Based on Qt 4.7.0(32 bit)

Comment: @DNT Actually I am using vectors in my game to save the states of 15 puzzle game. Size of vector could go even million sometimes. My program works fine If I have few no of shuffles in the game. I ran this application with other pc and that pc also crashed my application and error was different. Other pc showe that this error is due to abort().

Comment: If it's millions of bytes or integers it's fine, but if it's millions of large structures or qt widgets..., also, you might be using your vectors in unexpected ways - like I said, the reasons can be way too many to speculate without specifics. Try to assert every condition you expect to be true, every value range, in short add all preconditions in every function call and check post-conditions until some of those asserts start firing first, before your code crashes. Then you'll know what went wrong.

Comment: @DNT I have more than 100 functions. It will take too long to put assert on every function.

Comment: @DNT How to return the value of a variable in assert function? is there any way to see the exact value of variable when assert was failed?

Comment: only if you test in the normal way with an output function like cout << "at checkpoint #1234" << myvariable; for example before the assert, or by adding the same condition of the assert in a if (!<assert condition here>) clause that succeeds where the assert would fire, and print out your variable there.

Comment: @DNT I also tested my application in ubuntu today but it crashes too without any message. It just crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem: Actually I was accessing a vector location which was not available. `assert()` helped me to troubleshoot. Thanks @DNT